# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Entity

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I got a sample project, copied from somewhere else, when I am trying to run it in netbeans I am getting some error/exceptions in tomcat's console window.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Entity
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:167)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
```

javax.persistence is already added to my project. I even removed and re-added in netbeans but still same error. This error is when running the web applictation not when compiling.
[image]

Comment: You need to add the `Persistence Jar Files` to your BuildPath.

Comment: Which version of tomcat you are using ?

Comment: You are missing some jars regarding JPA

Comment: Ok, added some info on how to download the jar files. You need to create a directory called lib in your project set up, add the jars there, then include them in your build path . For this right click on project -> goto java build path -> add jars .

Comment: Are you getting tomcat 7 welcome page , when you start the server in your http://localhost:8080 or whatever your port no is set at ?

Comment: Yes I can see my web application. Its running fine. but in console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following `Jar Files` to your Build Path: -

- `javax.persistence_2.0.3.v201010191057.jar`
- `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa_2.3.0.v20110604-r9504.jar`
- `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.equinox_2.3.1.v20111018-r10243.jar`
- `org.eclipse.persistence.antlr_2.3.0.v20110604-r9504.jar`
- `org.eclipse.persistence.asm_2.3.0.v20110604-r9504.jar`

Preferably adding the first one will work, as `javax.persistence.Entity` is found in that `Jar` only. 
But you may also need to add the later ones, for working with `JPA`

Google them with the name of JPA Jars. You will get them.

Comment: how to add a jar file to build path?

Comment: @coure2011 See these links: - http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/11451/addtolibrary and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans

Comment: @coure2011 You need to create a `lib` folder under your Project directory, and add all the Jar files in that folder.

Comment: Only doing that will not help, he needs to import the jars in his build path from lib dir

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yeah that's what the links I gave tells. I gave to him so that he can understand it better..

Comment: what is "Import the jar in his build path"??? I found that javax.persistence is already showing in my Libraries folder in Netbeans

Comment: @coure2011 Go to the link I provided. It explains how to add the Jar files from lib folder to library.. `Right Click on your jar file -> Add to Library`

Comment: The jars may be present in your library folder, but that does not get them to your build path . For that do this :

right click on project -> goto java build path -> Then click your lib folder of the project, it will show you the jars u have not added . Then add the jars and do a build .

Comment: It also added in build path see the screenshot and updated info for question

Comment: @coure2011 Well, can't see your screenshot in office. :(

Answer (score 0):

The javax.persistence.Entity is a class inside the Java EE SDK library “javaee.jar“, you are missing this jar file in your project classpath.

refer this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-entity/

Comment: I don't think this is the right solution for Tomcat. You only need the JPA-API JAR file ... not all of the J2EE APIs. (You already have a lot of the J2EE APIs and implementation classes in Tomcat.)