# Tomcat 7 can't load javax.persistence

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, persistence

I am importing eclipse projects to a virtual machine. I changed libraries (change the paths and re-import the project because this VM only has C: and not D:). Tomcat does not load and shows this. All libraries are imported and the persistence.xml file is configured ok.

```
[2014-07-21 12:15:43] ERROR (InicializacionListener.java:142) - Excepcion cerrando DAO: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dominion.procop.listeners.InicializacionListener.contextInitialized(InicializacionListener.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
jul 21, 2014 12:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase com.dominion.procop.listeners.InicializacionListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/PersistenceException
    at com.dominion.procop.listeners.InicializacionListener.contextInitialized(InicializacionListener.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 10 more

jul 21, 2014 12:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error listenerStart
jul 21, 2014 12:15:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Falló en arranque del Contexto [/MyData] debido a errores previos
[2014-07-21 12:15:43]  WARN (InicializacionListener.java:53) - >>>>>>  FINALIZANDO SERVICIO   <<<<<<
[2014-07-21 12:15:43]  INFO (Sincronizador.java:117) - Sincronizador - FINAL
jul 21, 2014 12:15:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol startjava.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932851/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i deleted and copied again the .jars (Toplink) and now it works perfectly. (honestly, i dont know how now it works...)

Answer (score 1):

You miss the `javax.persistence_1.0.0.jar` in the classpath of your application or in classpath of tomcat.

Comment: I use toplink-essentials-agent.jar and toplink-essentials.jar. i have exactly the same .jars than the other workspace.

Comment: @S.Moreno you have the jars also in tomcat's `lib` directory?

Comment: i was using the "Add Library -> User Library" from Eclipse. Finally i deleted from this option and copied to the `lib` directory, now it works. Thank you for your help