# What's wrong with this Paypal Interface Service?

Tags: java, soap, paypal

This is my first attempt generating a web service client.  I'm at a loss how to rectify this error.

I have a PayPalAPIInterfaceService.java and Netbeans IDE inform me that's an error:

```
public PayPalInterfaceService(WebServiceFeature...features){

super(__getwsdlLocation(), PAYPALINTERFACESERVICE_QNAME, features);
```

Here's the error message:

> cannot find symbol symbol : method_getWsdlLocation() location: class
>   ebay.api.paypalapi.PayPalAPIInterfaceService

And the error log from Tomcat:

```
17-Oct-2012 06:24:16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/encoding/AnyContentType
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3934)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4429)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:514)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1473)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:824)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:196)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/encoding/AnyContentType
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1850)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:890)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1354)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:545)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:223)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.encoding.AnyContentType
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 50 more
```

I wonder if the cause is due to the url location of the wsdl which I have imported from local drive? and I have to make some ammendment somewhere.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "PayPalAPIInterfaceService", targetNamespace = "urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI", wsdlLocation = "file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Karen/Desktop/ShoppingCart/src/conf/xml-resources/web-services/NewWebServiceFromWSDL/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl")
public class PayPalAPIInterfaceService
    extends Service
```

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/encoding/AnyContentType
```

You are missing the axis jars required for calling the web service.

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.axis.encoding.AnyContentType

If you're using Tomcat, the jars should also be in web-inf/lib

Comment: But, I'm not using Axis anymore so I removed it, since I read that it's not necessary to use AXIS tool to generate the client in Netbean IDE.

Comment: That may be so, but you still have some classes in your code that are expecting it to be there, irrelevant to whether you should actually need it or not, the error you have is a ClassDeFoundError, which means it cant find the class (which should be in the jar).  Also you probably would need Axis if you are sending a SOAP response back.

Comment: OK.  How do I make Netbean IDE and tomcat find my class then?  I have tried looking into the Axis aar location thing etc but still getting the same error over and over again.  Hope to hear some advice. Tks.

Comment: Tomcat will find the class from web-inf/lib, Netbeans I'm not sure as I only really use eclipse but there should be some way to include it in the build path of the project.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans