# package net.proteanit.sql does not exist

Tags: netbeans

I am unable to import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils, Getting this error package net.proteanit.sql does not exist. What library am i missing and where to get it?

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you need to add that external `.jar` file which has this package. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) for seeking help in adding external jar to your project.

Comment: I have the same thought. This net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils , suppose to be from Jesper Report?

Comment: so get that `.jar` file and add it to your `classpath`.

Answer (score 1):

> Projects>> Project(Application)>> right click on libraries>> choose
>   properties>> Compile

If there is something broken (ex. rs2xml.jar), remove it and replace it as same as the object that you remove.