# How to share package between multiple projects in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a package that contains some classes that I want to use in many different projects.

Do I have to copy/paste that package's folder into every project folder I want to use it in, or can I somehow share the same copy of the package between multiple projects; so that, when I make a change to a package the change is being made into every project it is included in?

If this is not possible you can suggest something similar...

This didn't help....
[How to import user-defined package in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387986/how-to-import-user-defined-package-in-netbeans)

[How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)

Comment: Im not using NetBeans but even if it is possible -> It is bad idea.

Comment: why? than what would you do in my situation? copy/paste the same package into every project folder you want to use it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add one project to another: `properties -> Libraries -> Compile -> Add Project`.

Any changes made to the project that you are referencing will save. If you have a class called `test` and you refactor it to `test2`, it should change all of your imports also.

Comment: Netbeans 8.2, Java 1.8, Maven, project right-click → Properties, and there is no "Libraries" category