# Adding Morphia depandancy to a project?

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans, morphia

I'm a newbie when it comes to Morphia, and JAVA in general. As we can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Dependencies#Manually)

to use Morphia I should Add the dependencies above to my class-path and compile.

I am using Netbeans. I could not understand what should I do exactly. Could you please explain me step by step? thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you've posted shows how to add Morphia if you're using maven to import your dependencies.  It sounds like you're not doing this, so what you (probably) want to do instead is download the latest Morphia jar (currently 0.101.0) from:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.morphia/morphia

Then to add it to your classpath in Netbeans, see the answer to this question:

[How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)

You should then be able to use the Morphia library