# How do I get the opennlp api files recognized to compile?

Tags: java, api, netbeans, opennlp

I've downloaded the OpenNLP tools, and was able to get the command line tools to run after adding the right paths to my bash file, but I can't figure out how to get the api files to work with my IDE (Netbeans).
For the command line tools I'm pointing the path to the /bin directory.  There are four jar files in the /lib directory: jwnl-1.3.3.jar, opennlp-maxent-3.0.3.jar, opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar, opennlp-uima-1.5.3.jar.

Any help on where to put these files, and how to access the opennlp tools api in Netbeans would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To use the API (either training or tagging), you only need opennlp-tools-1.5.3.jar. In NetBeans, if you have external library dependencies, see this question:

[How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)