# How do I import from a jar file that is already in my library? (Netbeans Java)

Tags: java, json, netbeans, jar, import

I downloaded a .jar file from JSON lib:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/

Then I went to netbeans and imported the file into my library,
now how do I used JSONobject in my program?

I think I need to do some sort of import statement, but Im not sure

Thanks in advance, Im a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your try to use a Class from the library your IDE should suggest the correct import statement. (May have to save first to see the suggestion)

Alternatively you can manually:

```
import some.lib.Class;
```

Edit: I've downloaded your linked jar, added it to a new project's Build Path and the following code gives no errors:

```
package test;

import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class TestJSON
{
    JSONObject jsonObj;

    public TestJSON()
    {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    }
}
```

Can you give us some erors, warnings or stacktraces please.

See this question for how to go about adding jars to your build path in Netbeans: [How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)

Comment: This import did not allow for the usage of JSONobject

Comment: What, if any, errors or warnings do you get if you put `import net.sf.json.JSONObject;` directly after your package declaration at the top of your class file?

Comment: And do you have the jar added to your Build Path?

Comment: package net.sf.json does not exist

Comment: How do I add the jar to the build path? I added it to the library

Comment: See this question for how to add libraries to your build path in netbeans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans

Comment: Ok I used one of the methods over there and imported it to libraries under project properties

Answer (score 0):

You can find a simple yet detailed explanation of imports [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).
Short answer, Yes, you need the import directive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will find the imports you seek with

```
 import net.sf.json.*; // e.g. JSONObject
```

In the future, you can always run `jar tvvf json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar` and get the contents yourself. Further, in addition to the jar utility, you can open JAR file with any application that can read zip files (because jars are zip files).

Comment: Maybe the jar is broken? I could not open it with archive utility or any other program, also that import didnt work

Comment: Try [downloading](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/latest/download?source=files) it again.