# taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found

Tags: java, netbeans, package

I ma trying to run the [java project jsignpdf](https://github.com/kwart/jsignpdf/) and after importing the project i added some libraries which are required.

Now when running the project I get error like

```
taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

In my build.xml i have following related to it:

```
<taskdef name="jarbundler" classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${jarbundler.jar}"/>
        </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

So how this can be solved?

Comment: you need to add these jars to your project and add them to you build and class paths

Comment: It's an Eclipse project - import it into Eclipse ("Import existing project")

Answer (score 1):

Apparrently you also need to have some of the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) libraries in your classpath. The project you linked to seems already prepared for the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) - you will probably have to add the missing JAR library files in Netbeans manually as mentioned e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4879903/507519) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7598623/507519).

To be honest, however, maintaining any number of external JAR dependencies manually becomes *extremely* frustrating *very* quickly. You would be better off in the long run if you invested some time in one of the mainstream build and/or dependency management systems such as [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/). Such a system would take care of downloading the dependencies and setting up the classpath for you, without all the painful probing and poking...

Comment: ok. i added so many libraries which are required. still com.sun.pdfview is shown missing even though i add it from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/p/Downloadpdfrendererjar.htm

Comment: @ITresearcher: Perhaps you should try using the JAR files from the current project page: https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/downloads

Comment: Ok.now i have resolved all errors.But when i run the project i am getting error like "Target "run" does not exist in the project "JSignPdf". " What does it mean?

Comment: @ITresearcher: I assume that you need to create a `run` target using an appropriate class that contains a `main()` method. I have not really used NB, however, so I cannot help with that. You could try asking another question, if a Google search reveals nothing, which is rather unlikely...