# Exception on loading JDBC-ODBC driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, odbc, classnotfoundexception

I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` on loading `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` using `Class.forName()`.

I am using MySQL as Data Source and  I have added Data Source Name in ODBC Data Source Administrator (on Windows 8).

Here is the code:

```
class Connect {
     check() {
       try {

           Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

Comment: The jdbc-odbc bridge has been removed in Java 8.

Comment: did you try to Test connection in `ODBC Data Source Administrator` after configuring?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch then how to connect to Database?

Comment: Use a Type-4 JDBC driver.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` but i am getting same error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Now go and download the MySQL connector for Java.

Comment: Downloaded. Now how to add it as dependency in project? Do i need to import something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Java 8? The class is no longer present there ([more info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html)). You could install Java 7 if you need to use it.

Comment: How to connect to Database by using Java 8?

Comment: A JDBC driver exists for MySQL, use that instead. Here is an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

Comment: I tried using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` but i am getting same error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: You need to download the driver from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and add it as a dependency to your project.

Comment: How to add it as dependency to project? Do i need to `import` it? How?

Comment: That is done differently depending on which IDE you are using. If you are using NetBeans, check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans. For Eclipse, it is answered here: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once, and what i did was importing the mysql jdbc library that came with the product when i downloaded it, after that i used the driver as it is explained in the page:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

hope this could help you