# Project doesn't start on new PC with the newest version of Netbeans and Java SE Development Kit

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

### Apcahe Tomcat Log

```
17-Oct-2014 14:06:48.319 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class listeners.Initializer
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/HttpParams
    at mon.MainMon.openConnection(MainMon.java:72)
    at mon.MainMon.<init>(MainMon.java:38)
    at mon.MainMon.setJndiName(MainMon.java:221)
    at listeners.Initializer.contextInitialized(Initializer.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1496)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1437)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    ... 53 more

17-Oct-2014 14:06:48.319 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class ShutdownInitializer
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ShutdownInitializer.contextDestroyed(ShutdownInitializer.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4801)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1496)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1437)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Apache Tomcat

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.9\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.348 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;.
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.788 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.866 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.874 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.874 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.881 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1074 ms
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.944 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.944 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.9
17-Oct-2014 17:50:32.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
17-Oct-2014 17:50:33.826 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Oct-2014 17:50:34.045 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml has finished in 1,071 ms
17-Oct-2014 17:50:34.045 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\MDCWebDispatcher.xml
17-Oct-2014 17:50:34.045 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.672 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.680 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/MDCWebDispatcher] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.688 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\MDCWebDispatcher.xml has finished in 1,643 ms
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.688 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.797 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.797 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 109 ms
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.797 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.813 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Oct-2014 17:50:35.813 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2839 ms
17-Oct-2014 17:50:37.637 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MDCWebDispatcher]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
17-Oct-2014 17:50:38.198 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/MDCWebDispatcher]
17-Oct-2014 17:50:38.307 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\MDCWebDispatcher.xml
17-Oct-2014 17:50:38.346 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
17-Oct-2014 17:50:39.775 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
17-Oct-2014 17:50:39.783 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/MDCWebDispatcher] startup failed due to previous errors
17-Oct-2014 17:50:39.791 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\serega\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.9.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\MDCWebDispatcher.xml has finished in 1,484 ms
```

### My Program's run

```
ant -f "D:\\serg\\Projects2 - Copy\\MDCWebDispatcher" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false "-Dbrowser.context=D:\\serg\\Projects2 - Copy\\MDCWebDispatcher" run
init:
deps-module-jar:
CommonForgeClassesLib.init:
Deleting: D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\CommonForgeClassesLib\build\built-jar.properties
CommonForgeClassesLib.deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\CommonForgeClassesLib\build\built-jar.properties
CommonForgeClassesLib.wsimport-init:
CommonForgeClassesLib.wsimport-client-CpService:
files are up to date
CommonForgeClassesLib.wsimport-client-generate:
CommonForgeClassesLib.compile:
Copy libraries to D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\CommonForgeClassesLib\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\CommonForgeClassesLib\dist\CommonForgeClassesLib.jar"
CommonForgeClassesLib.jar:
machMonitoring.init:
Deleting: D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\build\built-jar.properties
machMonitoring.deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\build\built-jar.properties
CommonForgeClassesLib.init:
CommonForgeClassesLib.deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\build\built-jar.properties
CommonForgeClassesLib.wsimport-init:
CommonForgeClassesLib.wsimport-client-CpService:
files are up to date
CommonForgeClassesLib.wsimport-client-generate:
CommonForgeClassesLib.compile:
Copy libraries to D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\CommonForgeClassesLib\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\CommonForgeClassesLib\dist\CommonForgeClassesLib.jar"
CommonForgeClassesLib.jar:
machMonitoring.compile:
Copying 1 file to D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\build
Not copying library D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\<<<<<<< project.properties , it can't be read.
Copy libraries to D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\dist\lib.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\machMonitoring\dist\machMonitoring.jar"
machMonitoring.jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Copying 1 file to D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\MDCWebDispatcher\build\web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
Undeploying ...
undeploy?path=/MDCWebDispatcher
OK - Undeployed application at context path /MDCWebDispatcher
In-place deployment at D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\MDCWebDispatcher\build\web
Deployment is in progress...
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2Fserega%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2F2%2Fcontext5124608604393553249.xml&path=/MDCWebDispatcher
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /MDCWebDispatcher but context failed to start
D:\serg\Projects2 - Copy\MDCWebDispatcher\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1112: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong!

Comment: When looking at [HttpParams 4.3.2](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html) I see **Deprecated**. Look at the solutions they mention and rewrite to use a newer API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added httpclient-4.3.5.jar and httpcore-4.3.2.jar in my project, delete not needed libs and problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your code is saying it cannot find the HTTPParams class.
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.params.HttpParams`

This tells me that the appropriate Jars are not included.

The jar file that contains HttpParams is called HttpCore and can be found [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/).

This may not be the version you need, and it may not be all you need to have in your project.
You'll need to double check which jars you have included, and make sure they are the correct version you need.

I did notice that you're using Netbeans. If you're having trouble with Netbeans deploying to Tomcat, I suggest you look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) for how to include jar files in Netbeans to make sure they're included properly.

Let us know if this solves the problem and be sure to mark the answer you feel is the "Best Answer".

Comment: Joop Eggen did bring up something I missed. The HttpParams class has indeed been deprecated as of 4.3, if I'm reading this correctly. It says: _"use configuration classes provided 'org.apache.http.config' and 'org.apache.http.client.config'"._ You can read it for yourself [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html).

Comment: I don't understand,what I will do?

Comment: @user3704320 Let me see if I can break it down a bit. First you should know that you need to include libraries to run your code. These libraries are contained in files called "jars". They have an extension of ".jar". The "ClassNotFoundException" mentioned above means that for your program to run on Tomcat it needs the "HttpParams" Class. This is contained in the "HttpCore" library. It will be in a jar called "HttpCore 4.3.x.jar" or something similar. That jar file **must** be included in your project. To do this you'll need to do a little research to figure out how to include jars in Netbeans.

Comment: I understand you want to connect some jar with org.apache.http.config, because deprecated HttpParams?

Comment: Perhaps I should back up a step. Both org.apache.http.params.HttpParams and org.apache.http.config.* are in the library HttpCore 4.3. You simply need to include the HttpCore jar in your project. The deprecation comment, (see [here](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html)) also mentions that you should include the org.apache.http.client.config.* library. This is in a different jar called HttpClient. In short, download the HttpClient and HttpCore jars and include them in your project.

Comment: I do as you write, download http core and httpclient from [link](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi), but this is don't solved my problem...

Comment: @SergBash You say you downloaded the HttpCOre and HttpClient, but what did you do with them? What IDE are you using, or are you just trying to deploy to Tomcat from the command line? Just trying to understand a bit more about the situation, because I'm obviously missing something here.

Comment: I add httpcore-4.1.jar and httpclient-4.3.5.jar to project(Project->Properties->Libraries->Add Jar/Folder) in Netbeans 8.0.1.

Comment: Well, i solved my problem: I delete all libs and add by single each lib and look on missing references. As a result-many libs unused. Thank's all for participation!

Comment: @SergBash It would be great if you could answer your own question with what you did to solve it, and mark it as the best answer so that other people who view this question will be able to see what you did to solve it.