# How to use rabbitMQ?

Tags: java, netbeans, rabbitmq

I have downloaded RabbitMQ and seeking [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html). However I'm not in Java at all and I don't know how to solve problem.

Problem is that I get this error

```
error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
error: package com.rabbitmq.client does not exist import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;`
```

I have downloaded server and some client jars [from this website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html), but I don't know how to include all the stuff in Java Project.

Also I'm using netbeans 8.0.2

Comment: Maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans

Comment: @bigdestroyer Well I have tried right click Libraries->Add JAR/Folder and selected folder with JARs but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Do you get the same error after include the jar's to the classpath?

Comment: @bigdestroyer Yes, error is the same, maybe I'm using wrong JARs

Comment: Unzip the jar's in your local Maven repo and check if exists com/rabbitmq/client path inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That class is on `amqp-client` jar, be sure that you have that jar in your classpath.

If you are using maven, you can add:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${amqp.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

or donwload the jar from maven central:

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.rabbitmq%7Camqp-client%7C3.4.2%7Cjar

Comment: You may be right, but after googling that file, I'm back to webpage I have taken other JARs, but it doesn't contain that one. do you know where can I download that file?

Comment: Thanks! Works now, I have downloaded from repo.