# How can I run a jar file from my main Java app? Where jar file must be in my Java project

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I am a new Java Application developer. I am developing java application by Netbeans. Please help me to run another jar file1 from my main jar file. Where I dont know about the internal classes of java file1.

Comment: Link the Jar file into your project (via the Libraries node).  The class are now available for you to use

Comment: Visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 1):

Add jar files into your project. Then import jar file(class) into your code.
For instance, jar file name is ExternalJar.jar.. you could import as following

```
import ExternalJar.yourClassName;
```

Comment: Actually i dont know about internal structure of that java file.

Comment: If you don't know anything about the internals of the jar you need to parse its manifest. The string after Main-Class is the main class you should call to run the jar. Of course if the jar is a library it won't contain this attribute.

Comment: first get to know about that jar(class,method...).