# Swing L&F - Import and implementation

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I built a game on java and now I want to make it looks better, I used the default  "Nimbus" LookAndFeel but it's just not good enough.
I tried install some other themes by building the .jar files into class path but it didn't work all the times I tried it showed all kinds of messages, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. I would be grateful  if someone will explain to me how to make that work!

Comment: *" it showed all kinds of messages"* Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way. Add to the classpath the theme you want. Search and copy the qualified name and, finally, this:

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("set.qualified.name.here");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
            | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it already  many times, this is the result every single time:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException;

Comment: please, paste all exceptions

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] looks = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
    for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo look : looks) {
      System.out.println(look.getClassName());
    }
  }
}
```

will list all the available look and feel. check what you like most.
you can also check some really amazing l&f from http://www.jwrapper.com/blog/6-great-look-and-feels-to-make-your-java-app-pretty

Comment: I know that site, but I don't know how to import the jar file into class path.

Comment: You need to have java 1.6 or above on Oracle JVM for Nimbus to work, do you see it listed when you run the above code?
and about importing the jar file, are you trying command line or eclipse? based on that you can google. info is available widepread. you may go through http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html

Comment: I don't get it, I tried those methods and didn't success... I'm using NetBeans and it's not creating a META-INF folder... XD also all the command line examples are just won't work to me.

Comment: I used that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans  in order to include the .jar into classpath but when I set the look and feel it's showing those errors:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/HierarchicalStreamDriver
 at com.alee.laf.WebLookAndFeel$2.propertyChange(WebLookAndFeel.java:855)

Comment: did nimbus l&f work for you? that is supplied with java 1.6 or higher.

Comment: Yes that work, but I don't like that looks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what the e.stackprint shows:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alee.laf
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.loadSystemClass(SwingUtilities.java:1874)
at javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.java:582)
at blackjack.GameGUI.main(GameGUI.java:498)
```

Comment: Add the theme to the classpath