# JUnit Transformation Error In NetBeans

Tags: java, testing, junit

I made a project in Netbeans and afterwards i ran some JUnit tests, everything was OK. Then I transfered the src and test files to another computer and i got the following errors:[image]

[image]

What should I do to get rid of those errors?I am new to java so I am not sure why this is hapening! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Set the build path for those jars. this might help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans

Comment: Alright! Thank you very much!

Comment: John is it got fixed?

Comment: Yeah everything is ok now

Comment: you can accept my answer if you your issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of you didn't set the class path for dependency jars, so make sure all the jars are available in classpath of your netbeans project.

[Refer](http://.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)  this how to set buildpath