# "Operation not allowed after ResultSet Closed" exception during MySQL to Java Netbeans Connection

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am making a email management system in Java Netbeans IDE. This is a code for the registration page. It is always throwing error no matter what I tried.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/email management system","root", "ok" );
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from inbox");

         Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from curlogin");

       String fname = "";

        while(rs.next())
        {
            fname = rs1.getString("name");
            String sender = rs.getString("First");
        String reciever = rs.getString("recipent");
            if(reciever.equals(fname))
            model.addElement(sender);
        }
        list.setModel(model);

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(inbox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(inbox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: The driver JAR is missing at runtime.

Comment: sir will you please elaborate a little, I am an absolute beginner.

Comment: Are you running this inside a web application container like Tomcat?

Comment: No, just a simple Java application

Comment: That doesn't really solve my problem, you can take a look at the Url, it appears correct. and another thing is that I have been using same kind of code for some of my other projects but it didn't threw the error back then.

Comment: You need to add the MySQL JAR to your NetBeans dependencies.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans).

Comment: Oh I figured it out, I had interchanged the position of the url and the username, password. Thanks for your valuable time :)

Comment: You don't need two queries for this. You should be doing a JOIN.