# I can't import TAudioFileFormat

Tags: java, import, mp3, netbeans-6.9, tritonus

I use netbeans 6.9.1.

All I want to do is to get the total length of an mp3 song. What I know is this requires tritonus.jar and I have downloaded that and I have imported it to my src file of the package. And it appears in my projects tab under the package in which the JFrame I want to import it(TAudioFileFormat) lives.

To import it, I type

```
import org.tritonus.share.sampled.file.TAudioFileFormat;
```

Is there any error in what I have typed? Because everytime the error shows that

```
package org.tritonus.share.sampled.file does not exist
```

and I can very well see it there...

Also, when I type the import, when I put a full stop after org, it doesn't show tritonus in that drop down thing.

I apologise for not knowing the proper terms of things.

[image: This is a picture of my current situation.]

Comment: You have to add the class to your build path. I can't tell you how to do so, since I don't know the IDE you're working with. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH!!!!!!! I had completely forgotten about that. I'm such an idiot. Thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this for about a week now...