# ControlsFX sample source not found

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I am trying to access controlsFX (controlsfx-samples-8.40.12.jar); When I access the FX sampler jar file I am able to see the layout and the function but I get nothing for the sample source code or the css. I have opened a ticket but I was wondering if anyone had similar issue.

I tried to access it from windows and mac.

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

error code;

```
Initialising FXSampler sample scanner...
    Discovering projects...
        Found project 'ControlsFX', with sample base package 'org.controlsfx.samples'
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler.getResource(FXSampler.java:330)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler.getResource(FXSampler.java:326)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler.getSourceCode(FXSampler.java:356)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler.formatSourceCode(FXSampler.java:367)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler.updateTab(FXSampler.java:318)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler.access$300(FXSampler.java:72)
    at fxsampler.FXSampler$4.invalidated(FXSampler.java:175)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
```

[Click here to visit the ticket I opened](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/779/sample-source-not-found)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) if you use Netbeans.

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. Any headway? Can you include a link to the ticket?

Comment: Updated with the ticket link