# JavaFX, not have JFXButtons and all

Tags: java, javafx

I do not have any components in the library like JFXPassordField, JFXButton and many others. Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: The buttons in JavaFX are called [Button](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those components are part of a third party library called JFoenix.

You can find more information about them here: https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix

You can download the `.jar` file from there or

If you are using maven as dependency management you can add as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

or if you are using gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:1.4.0'
}
```

but you can find all of these informations on the link that I have added.

**How to add jar to classpath:**

Eclipse: [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

IntelliJ: [Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

NetBeans: [How to add a JAR in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans)

Comment: Where to upload these files?

Comment: Where to upload these files?

Comment: I have updated the answer if you mean that by __uploading__.

Comment: In which folder do I put these files that I just downloaded?

Comment: It depends, What did you so far? Did you downloaded the `.jar` file? If yes then please tell me which IDE are you using and I can help you integrating it.

Comment: Answer edited, you can look for how to add them to the classpath.