# How to download and use Commons.Lang in java project?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to reverse an integer array in java using Arrays.toString(reverse(arrayname) method but not able to correctly use its header file. [image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiAxm.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang3;

public class ReverseDisplay 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int arr[]=new int[5];
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Element # "+(i+1));
        arr[i]=input.nextInt();
    }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverse(arr)));

    }

}
```

Comment: Use inline code instead of images. Also, very unclear

Comment: You mean Apache Commons Lang? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: instead of image of code (just a few lines?!) paste it as TEXT - much easier to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put commons-lang jar in your classpath (either in IDE or classpath param in commandline or add dependency if you use maven/gradle)

if you want to do it manually you need to download jar first: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

Java can import only classes that are on the classpath.

Comment: how do i put common-lang jar  class path in net-beans.

Comment: I don't use netbeans, but when you download from above link there will be jar file inside, and you have to add it in netbeans to classpath:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans