# Java connecting to mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

hello i have mysql running on my mac and i am trying to write a java script to connect to it:

```
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://local:3306/test";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }catch (SQLException e){
    System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

however i keep getting this error message

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://local:3306/test

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have the mysql connector/j (jdbc) driver on your runtime classpath. Also, it's `localhost` (not `local`).

Comment: I have changed the local to localhost however i thought you did not have to add the driver on the "/Users/Username/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 2/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar" java 8.0 connector (i have imported it)

Comment: Add also this `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); `

Comment: I keep seing this online i thought i was for older versions of the connector.

Comment: however when i add it i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
 at testforairbus.TestFortest.main(TestForTest.java:22)
Java Result: 1

Comment: what is the ide you are using?

Comment: I am Using Netbeans

Comment: So fix that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add the Mysql jdbc driver as a external library. You can find the jar file from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) guides how to add the library in netbeans. Other thing is `local` must be `localhost`

```
private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }catch (SQLException e){
    System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done all of that the mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 is added as a library and i import it  at the beginning of the code however when the class.forName i always get an error

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown at testforairbus.TestFortest.main(TestForTest.java:22)  this one to be precise

Comment: I think you have added a wrong library. Did you refer the which link i have given in the answer for the mysql connector jar file. latest version of original mysql connector is _5.1.46_

Comment: wow it worked with your version is this an issue ?WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'.

Comment: it works with the older version thank you very much for your time

Comment: @OlivierMaxwell actually its not the older version.its the latest.You were using mysql connector for .net that is totally different from java.You need java mysql connector for java projects

Answer (score 0):

After having the driver in your classpath you need to add the below line before getting connection and change the local to localhost in CONN_STRING:

DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());

Something like this:

```
try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver ());
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("Connected");
    }catch (SQLException e){
    System.err.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: trying that just results in more errorsException in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
.........

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: im using jdk 8, netbeans 8.0.2 and the mysql connector 8.0.11

Comment: Just double check that your JDK and JRE are of the same version and then try running the code with a version 5 series of MySQL connector.

Comment: its works with an older version i still dont understand why but thank you very much