# Read Data from Excel in Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm really confused I've read many articles but none helped,
I want to know how to read data from Excel using java (I'm using NetBeans).
I need to know which library to use, and source code.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file)

Comment: Thanks Berger, but I downloaded apache POI but I have an error (package org.wickedsource.docxstamper.DocxStamper doesn't exist). I already downloaded the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org/) to read Excel, Word, etc.

There is a good tutorial on [TutorialsPoint Apache Poi Quick Guide](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_quick_guide.htm), you should check it out there first.

Below, there is an example code for you, it reads from the WriteSheet.xlsx excel file and prints all the rows-columns to console:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("WriteSheet.xlsx"));

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Iterator < Row >  rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();

  while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
     row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
     Iterator < Cell >  cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

     while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
           case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
              System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t ");
              break;

           case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
              System.out.print(
              cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t\t ");
              break;
        }
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
  fis.close();
```

**Edit:** You should check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879903/how-to-add-a-jar-in-netbeans) if you have got problems in adding jar file to netbeans.

But, if you have got problems in adding the necessary jar files, first you should download the poi-bin zip file in the [Apache Poi Download Page](https://poi.apache.org/download.html). After that, you should add these jars to your env(Versions may vary in time):

```
poi-3.17.jar
ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar
```

Comment: Hi Burak, could you please explain how can I downlaod Apache Poi on mac (netbeans). I'm confused in that. thanks!

Comment: Hi Mona, I've updated my answer because of I couldn't fit my reply in the comments section. Hope it helps :)